# Restore all git branches on remote repository from local

Tags: git, github

I have a local git repository containing code right from the start of the project. But the remote repository is completely deleted (all branches and commit history are gone).

Is there a way to restore all the branches (and commit history) on the remote repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method for restoring the missing remote depends on whether you will push to a new empty repository, or clone from your own copy.

#### To push to a new empty repository

First, create the repository on the server (`git init --bare` and any other setup required).  Make sure you have push access to that server.  You can add its URL via, e.g.:

```
git remote add new-server ssh://user@host/path/to/repo.git
```

assuming you will use ssh to push.  If pushing via https, make the obvious adjustments.

At this point you can just run:

```
git push --tags new-server 'refs/remotes/origin/**:refs/heads/*'
```

This pushes all your remote-tracking names for the original remote `origin`, creating them as branch names on `new-server`.  If your remote was not named origin, make the obvious substitution.  The `--tags` pushes all tags as well.

#### To clone to a new repository

To prepare the local repository so that it is suitable for use as a clone, we will want to create a local branch name corresponding to each remote-tracking name.  I will assume here that each remote-tracking name is named `origin/whatever`; if not, replace `origin` with the appropriate string.

To do this:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/remotes/origin |
    while read rref; do
        lref=${rref#refs/remotes/origin/} # strip the boilerplate
        [ "$lref" = HEAD ] && continue # skip origin/HEAD
        git branch $lref $rref ||
            echo "WARNING: did not create $lref, make sure that's OK"
    done
```

This is likely to print at least one warning, about not being able to create `master`.  For each warning—each local branch you have that already corresponds to a remote-tracking name—make sure the branch up to date or ahead of the remote-tracking name.

Now make sure that the client is reachable via whatever URL you intend to use, then, on the server, run:

```
cd server/path/to
git clone --mirror --bare ssh://user@host/client/path/to/repo.git
```

This will create a bare clone named `repo.git` in `server/path/to`.  You may want to delete the new clone's `origin` by doing:

```
cd repo.git
git remote remove origin
```

since presumably you never want to re-mirror the repository you just cloned.